# Allowing some html tags from user input using html/template in Go

Tags: google-app-engine, templates, go

I am using Go html/template package for rendering user inputs received from HTML form. As the package html/template is preventing script injection from user inputs, all the html tags will be converted into their &...; formats.

However, I am planning to use WYSIWYG input field which allows users to input some styling tags such as the < strong > tag. I am using template function solution.

```
funcs := template.FuncMap{
    "marktag": func(text string) template.HTML {
        output := strings.Replace(template.HTMLEscapeString(text), "&lt;strong&gt;", "<strong>", -1)
        output = strings.Replace(output, "&lt;/strong&gt;", "</strong>", -1)
        return template.HTML(output)
    },
}
```

Which works OK. However, I have to call strings.Replace(..) function many times if I need to convert the other tags too such as

```
<ul><li></li></ul>
<emphasize></emphasize>
<code></code>
```

and so on

Furhermore, I found it hard to deal with the css style like

```
<p style="color: #343434"></p>
```

Now I have to check for

```
<p
```

as well. Is there any ideal solution to this problem?

Comment: This is a non-trivial problem to solve securely, but take a look at https://github.com/microcosm-cc/bluemonday

Comment: Easier and more secure would be not to use HTML syntax for formatting, but some other syntax like wiki or phpBB, and convert that to HTML when you want to render it. Might be even easier/friendlier to the users.